# With PowerPivots, find items that appear *only* in one category

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, powerpivot

With PowerPivot, how do I find items only in one category? Here's an example:

`item   category    number
obera      f6        7
artois     f7        2
obera      f7        3
ella       f6        9`

If I choose `f6`, the output for this example would be:

`ella`

(it would not contain obera since that also appears in the f7 category). Thanks in advance.

Edit: what I want to do is for each category (of which I have a lot), display items that only appear under that category and nowhere else.

Comment: I think you need to revise your example - obera does not appear in the f7 category.

Answer (score 1):

I built a solution to this using the Power Query Add-In.  You can download it from my OneDrive - it's the file **Power Query demo - items that are only in one category**

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

Here's a description of how I built it:

Using Power Query, I created a Query ("Table1") from the Excel table.  I unchecked the option to Load to worksheet - this is just for input to the next Query.

I then created another Query ("Table1 multi-category") from the same Excel table.  In that Query I Merged the "Table1" Query, joining on Item.  Then I expanded the Item and Category columns from "Table1".  Note that at this point I have increased the number of rows, covering all combinations of Item.

Then I added a Custom Column "multi-category".  The formula is just:

`[category] <> [NewColumn.category]`

I already joined on Item, so this tests whether there are multiple categories for this item.  Then I filtered on this column, just keeping the TRUE values.

I then added a Group By to group by Item and Category, and get the Max value of the "multi-category" column - this caters to the scenario when an item has more than 2 categories.

Finally I removed up the "working out" columns, and again unchecked the option to Load to worksheet - this is just for input to the next Query.

Next I created another Query ("Table1 final"), again starting from the original Excel table. This time I Merged in the "Table1 multi-category" Query, joining on Item and Category, and including rows that don't match.

Then I expanded and renamed the "multi-category" column, and replaced null values with FALSE.  This Query is delivered to a new table on a new sheet "Multi-category".

Finally I built a pivot table on that new table on the "Multi-category" sheet.  The "multi-category" column tells you which Items exist in multiple categories.

It's obviously quite a few steps to get to this point.  However each step in isolation is quite simple and fairly easy to understand, given the WYSIWYG Power Query editor.  It's certainly a lot easier to follow than debugging VBA code and 100x better than trying to debug Excel formulas.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm not familiar with Power Query, but am looking into it and looking at your sheet now.